# Is there an uniformly continuous $[0,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb R$ surjection?

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

I think there isn't but I can't write a proof. I tried assuming that such function is (as it must be) continuous, and showing that it can't be uniformly cont., but I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: You can do this with piecewise linear functions of derivative $\pm 1$. First, go from $(0,0)$ to $(1,1)$, then from $(1,1)$ to $(2,-1)$, then further to $(5,2)$ and so on.

Comment: I meant $(3,-1)$ and then $(6,2)$ and so on.

Comment: Yes, I love this idea.

Comment: By the way, @FriedrichPhilipp's idea was the one I had in mind before I decided that the "smoothed-out" $\sqrt x \sin \sqrt x$ would be shorter to _describe_: The amplitude of the piecewise linear zig-zag grows asymptotically as $\sqrt x$, and so does the number of zero crossings so far (because that equals the amplitude). So the zig-zag would be approximated by $c \sqrt x \sin( c \pi \sqrt x)$ for some appropriate $c$, and throwing away the constant factors is not going to lose us the uniform continuity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about $x\mapsto \sqrt{x}\sin(\sqrt x)$?

Answer (score 4):

The function $$f(x) = x \sin ( \log (x+1))$$
has bounded derivative (hence it is uniformly continuous) and oscillates between $+ \infty$ and $- \infty$ (hence it is surjective).

Comment: Damn... I was about to post this one (after extensive trial-and-error). For what this comment is worth: $\sin$ is a natural idea because of the oscillations, and putting something "slow" instead is to temper the slope -- to prevent it from growing as the function oscillates with bigger and bigger amplitude (so, intuitively, something "slower than $x$" is needed inside the $\sin$).

Comment: Indeed this was my idea.